# Controlling a relay with a momentary button in Python

Tags: python, gpio

I was able to control the relay with a momentary button with the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)

def callback_func(pin):
    if GPIO.input(17):
        GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)
    else:
        GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)

GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.BOTH, callback=callback_func, bouncetime=200)

def main():
    while True:
        print "Not blocking! You're free to do other stuff here"
        time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This, however seems to be only once. Once I release the botton and try again, regardless how much time in between it won't work. Is there a specific reason it will only run once?

Preferably I would want to be able to keep using this button without having to stop the python script and restarting it to get a one-time button relay action.

Thanks!

Comment: at a quick glance, the two possibilities are: you need to add more code into your while loop, and/or you need to reset the gpio pin out to the initial state. What do you want pin out to be when the button is depressed. By the way, I suggest putting all of the setup statements into a setup function...

Comment: OP, I wrote the code you're using from memory and couldn't test it at the time. I see now that the de-bouncing caused the script to miss the rising edge that occurs when the button is released - at least if you release it quickly. I've updated my answer to your original question accordingly. In case you get jitter without any debouncing, consider adding "bouncetime" back in but set it to a very low value - it's one of those things that need tweaking and testing since all buttons and fingers are slightly different. Anyway, glad you figured it out and got it working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the bouncetime completly fixed the issue. So:

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.BOTH, callback=callback_func, bouncetime=200)
```

to

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.BOTH, callback=callback_func)
```